# Function `tbl()` does not work with hive table under ODBC connection

Tags: r, dplyr, hive, dbplyr

When I try to connect to a Hive table using:

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), 'MyDataBase')
db_tbl <- dplyr::tbl(con, dbplyr::in_schema('my_schema','my_table'))
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("tbl") :    no applicable method for 'tbl' applied
to an object of class "Hive"
```

I understand that I am passing "Hive" object to `tbl` which now is not applicable. However, this code used to work at least in past versions of `dplyr` and `dbplyr`. I looked up in the documentation about any changes in the arguments of `tbl` function, but nothing it says about any changes from previous versions, even in the NEWS section of the packages.

Can you help me find out what should it be the new acceptable arguments for `tbl` function to read a Hive table in R?

The version of the packages are: `dplyr 1.1.4` and `dbplyr 2.4.0`. Running in Windows 10, `R Version 4.3.2`

Comment: The Hive object will be the connection. Have you tested and confirmed the database connection is working correctly? For example, you could use `DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM my_schema.my_table)` or similar to test the connection using the DBI package.

Comment: It might also be insightful to `print(con)` and/or `print(class(con))` incase this highlights something unusual has taken place with the creation of the connection.

Comment: thanks @Simon.S.A., I actually tried that as well getting a similar error. The issue I assume is that `tbl` in the latest `dplyr` version has a slightly different structure.

Comment: If a direct query of the database using DBI (without using `tbl`) fails then the problem will be with the connection. Otherwise, it seems likely that you have found a bug in the current version of dplyr or dbplyr and should submit a bug report on the relevant GitHub page.